# How to add variable values inside pdo->query

Tags: php, pdo

I want to upgrade my current code which is constantly sql injected with PDO.

Currently I'm stuck with using a variable inside a PDO query.

If I have two arguments like this

```
  $rowsPerPage = 3;

  // by default we show first page
  $pageNum = 1; 

  if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
     $pageNum = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
  }

  $offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;
```

And I have query like this

```
$STH = $DBH->query("SELECT News.ID, LEFT(NewsText,650), Title, AID, Date, imgID," .
        "DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d.%m.%Y.') as formated_date " .
        "FROM News, Categories, NewsCheck  WHERE Name LIKE '%News - Block%' AND CID=Categories.ID AND JID=News.ID ". 
        "ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage");
```

PDO reports an error in last line of the query ORDER BY
When I replace these line with 
 `"ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT3,3");` everything work.

So how to add variable values inside PDO::query ?

Updated:
Thanks to answer bellow I have updated my code like this

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT News.ID, LEFT(NewsText,650), Title, AID, Date, imgID," .
            "DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d.%m.%Y.') as formated_date " .
            "FROM News, Categories, NewsCheck  WHERE Name LIKE '%News - Block%' AND CID=Categories.ID AND JID=News.ID ". 
            "ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT :offset, :rowsPerPage;");

$STH->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH->bindParam(':rowsPerPage', $rowsPerPage, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$STH->execute();
```

But error occured:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''-3', '3'' at
>   line 1' in /pdo/test.php:42 Stack trace: #0
>   /pdo/test.php(42): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /pdo/test..

**Second Update**
Changed from PARAM_STR TO PARAM_INT like this

```
$STH->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$STH->bindParam(':rowsPerPage', $rowsPerPage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Everything works.

Comment: assign the query string to a variable, var_dump() the results and post here please.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You want to use **prepared statements** and **query parameters** like the following:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT your_column FROM your_table WHERE column < :parameter');
$sth->bindParam(':parameter', $your_variable, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

Using variables directly in your query will not protect you from SQL injections, even if you are using PDO. Parameters are the only good way to prevent them.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm confused now. Using vars inside query will not protect me from sql inj. attacks, should I be secure from sql injections with your example?

Comment: Yes, because in my example I used `PDO:bindParam` which will replace accordingly `:parameter` by `$your_variable`. `bindParam` will also make sure there is no special characters in your query.

Comment: Use `PDO::PARAM_INT` instead of `PDO::PARAM_STR` since your parameters are numbers.